# How to update table when Email is on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

```
USE [ASPDryrun]
GO

  UPDATE [dbo].[Users]
    SET [ID] = [IU].[PersNo], 
        [CostCenter] = [CC].[CostCenterID], 
        [OrgUnit] = [OU].[OrgUnitID]
   FROM [dbo].[Users], 
        [dbo].[Import_UserData] AS [IU], 
        [dbo].[CostCenters] AS [CC], 
        [dbo].[OrgUnits] AS [OU]
  WHERE [CC].[ID] = [IU].[CostCtr]
    AND [OU].[ID] = [IU].[OrgUnit]
    AND [IU].[CorporateEmail] IN (SELECT [Email] 
                                    FROM [dbo].[Users])

GO
```

I want to update the info of some users when they have the email on the other table. But this query update all users and don't know what's wrong, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You don't have any join condition relating the `dbo.Users` table to the other tables in your query.

Comment: Maybe I should add this condition: `AND [IU].[CorporateEmail] = [dbo].[Users].[Email]`

Email is the unique field for compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could fix the problem with only another condition more. Here is the result:

```
USE [ASPDryrun]
GO
        UPDATE [dbo].[Users]
        SET [ID] = [IU].[PersNo],
            [CostCenter] = [CC].[CostCenterID],
            [OrgUnit] = [OU].[OrgUnitID]
        FROM [dbo].[Import_UserData] AS [IU],
             [dbo].[CostCenters] AS [CC],
             [dbo].[OrgUnits] AS [OU],
             [dbo].[Users] AS [U]
        WHERE [CC].[EricssonID] = [IU].[CostCtr]
          AND [OU].[EricssonID] = [IU].[OrgUnit]
          AND [IU].[CorporateEmail] = [U].[Email]
        GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Would explicit joins work better?  Just guessing, not sure what data is actually in these...
 Like

```
USE [ASPDryrun]
GO

  UPDATE [dbo].[Users]
    SET [ID] = [IU].[PersNo], 
        [CostCenter] = [CC].[CostCenterID], 
        [OrgUnit] = [OU].[OrgUnitID]
   FROM [dbo].[Users], 
        join [dbo].[Import_UserData] AS [IU] on [IU].[CorporateEmail]=users.[email]
        join [dbo].[CostCenters] AS [CC] on [CC].[ID] = [IU].[CostCtr]
        join [dbo].[OrgUnits] AS [OU] on [OU].[ID] = [IU].[OrgUnit]
```